# several values per date for annotated time line with googleVis package

Tags: r, google-visualization, annotatedtimeline, googlevis

It seems to me that the annotated time line produced by the `gvisAnnotatedTimeLine()` function of the googleVis R package only allows a unique value for each date. Is there a way to plot several values per date with `gvisAnnotatedTimeLine()` ? Otherwise is there an alternative to do so ?

Comment: What do you mean but unique value for each data? many values for each date means taht you have many time lines , or many time series...and [gVisAnnotaedTimeLine allow to draw multiple time series](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/annotatedtimeline#Configuration_Options). So I am little confused..

Comment: Each day there are several measurements. The "time line" could be done with the average value by day, but I'd like to plot the individual values too.